# Spring configuration c3p0 error

Tags: java, c3p0

Spring from the external file db.properties configuration c3p0, $ {user} out of the value is not correct, take out my computer user name.
if `user1=root`

```
public class Value {
    private String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public void say() {
        System.out.println(value);
    } 
}


<bean id="value" class="cc.bluecode.beans.Value">
    <property name="value" value="${user1}"></property>
</bean>
```

[The output is correct ✔️ :root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ParbV.jpg)

but,if
`user=root`

```
public class Value {
    private String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public void say() {
        System.out.println(value);
    } 
}


<bean id="value" class="cc.bluecode.beans.Value">
    <property name="value" value="${user}"></property>
</bean>
```

[Output error ❌:bluecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEinc.jpg)

Please tell me why God told me,thank you!

Comment: It's like you have double configurations for "user" value somewhere in another properties file maybe. Try to check the properties files you declare in spring xml configuration.

Comment: Thank you, but really only one

Comment: How if you change the key "user" to "username", and set the property like this `<property name="value" value="${username}"></property>` does the same thing still happen?

Comment: Only in the case of user will be